# Why is first-order logic defined as a collection of formal systems?

Tags: logic, formal-theory

I think I understand what a formal system is and what formal languages are. But I have trouble grasping why first-order logic  is referred  to as [a collection of formal systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) whereas propositional calculus is considered just [a formal system.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Terminology)
What makes the difference? What is the reason behind this definition? What does "a collection of formal systems" mean?

Comment: Would you have a reference where the two different descriptions are used?  This might help provide an answer.

Comment: @FrankHubeny I've added references to wikipedia pages that make this distinciton

Comment: Propositional calculus is just one form of first order logic, (standard) predicate calculus is another, so are [natural deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction) and [sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus). They differ by syntax of expressions, axioms, inference rules, etc.

Answer (score 5):

FOL is the "natural" logic environment to formalize mathematical theories.

Propositional calculus, instead, is only a "toy": it is based on a very simplified "model" of language that is not useful to develop interesting theories, but can be used efficiently to study the basic properties of a formal system : consistency, completeness, etc.

With FOL we have the "logical engine", i.e. the language with axioms and rules, and we usually study it in a similar way to the study of propositional calculus, in order to understand the basic meta-logic properties.

But, in addition to it, we are interested to add to the "logical engine" suitable non-logical constants, like **∈** ("in"), the binary relation of set theory, or **+** and **×** ("plus" and "times"), the basic arithmetical operations, with suitable *axioms* that govern their behaviour.

Thus, according to the specific mathematical symbols and axioms introduced, we have different formal mathematical theories : [first order arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic), [first-order set theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/ZF.html), and so on, all based on the same underlying logic : *first-order predicate calculus with equality*.

---

See also [List of first-order theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_first-order_theories).

Comment: “*FOL is the "natural" logic environment to formalize mathematical theories. Propositional calculus, instead, is only a "toy": it is based on a very simplified "model" of language that is not useful to develop interesting theories.*” This is a philosophical viewpoint or persuasion, not a de facto principle of modern logic.